# Adding link to d3js force layout cause bad data in nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a d3js side project where I am using the force layout to show nodes and lines to represent a graph. I have laid out the code such that the graph can be dynamically updated. I am doing this by:

1. Clearing force.nodes() then force.links()
2. Pushing all the nodes I want to add to force.nodes()
3. Updating the graph (join, enter, update, exit)
4. Pushing all the links I want with references to the nodes in force.nodes() to force.links
5. Updating the graph (join, enter, update, exit)

This works as long as I only have nodes to display, but as soon as I attempt to push a link to force.links then all hell breaks loose and the two nodes end up hiding in the top left corner.

Looking at the DOM I can see the following:

[image: DOM]

As you can see, the transform/translate parameters contain NaN values. So something blew up in my face but after two days of bug hunting I suspect that I am missing something here and need to take a cold shower.

I have stripped down my code to the smallest set that can reproduce the error. Please note from it that the nodes display fine until a link is pushed into force.links. No links are being drawn, only nodes, but the act of pushing a link where it belongs is disrupting the data in the nodes. This way of updating a graph should work as per the examples I have seen.

```
d3.json("data/fm.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    function chart(elementName) {

        // look for the node in the d3 layout
        var findNode = function(name) {
            for (var i in nodes) {
                if (nodes[i]["name"] === name) return nodes[i];
            };
        };           

        var width = 960, // default width
            height = 450, // default height
            color = d3.scale.category10(),
            force = d3.layout.force(),
            nodes = force.nodes(),
            links = force.links(),
            vis,
            runOnceFlag = true;

        vis = d3.select(elementName)
                .append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("id", "svg")
                .attr("pointer-events", "all")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
                .attr("perserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
                .append('svg:g');            

        var update = function() {               

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) {
                        return d.name;
                    });

            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .call(force.drag);

            nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("r", 12)
                    .attr("id", function (d) {
                        return "Node;" + d.name;
                    })
                    .attr("class", "nodeStrokeClass")
                    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

            nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
                    .attr("class", "textClass")
                    .attr("x", 14)
                    .attr("y", ".31em")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.name;
                    });

            node.exit().remove();

            force.on("tick", function () {

                node.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    console.log(d);
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                }); 

            });

            // Restart the force layout.
            force
                .charge(-120)
                .linkDistance( function(d) { return d.value * 10 } )
                .size([width, height])
                .start();
        };

        var a = graph.nodes[0];
        var b = graph.nodes[1]
        nodes.push(a);
        update();
        nodes.push(b);
        update();
        var c = {"source": findNode('a'), "target": findNode('b')}
        // the line below causes the error
        links.push(c);
        update()           
    };
    ///
    chart('body');
});
```

This is my data:

```
{
    "nodes":[
      {"name":"a", "group":1},
      {"name":"b", "group":2},
      {"name":"c", "group":3},
      {"name":"d", "group":4},
      {"name":"e", "group":5},
      {"name":"f", "group":6},
      {"name":"g", "group":7},
      {"name":"h", "group":1},
      {"name":"i", "group":2},
      {"name":"j", "group":3},
      {"name":"k", "group":4},
      {"name":"l", "group":5},
      {"name":"m", "group":6},
      {"name":"n", "group":7}
  ],
    "links":[
      {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
      {"source":2,"target":3,"value":1},
      {"source":4,"target":5,"value":1},
      {"source":7,"target":8,"value":1},
      {"source":9,"target":10,"value":1},
      {"source":11,"target":12,"value":1},
      {"source":0,"target":5,"value":1},
      {"source":1,"target":5,"value":1},
      {"source":0,"target":6,"value":1},
      {"source":1,"target":6,"value":1},
      {"source":0,"target":7,"value":1},
      {"source":1,"target":7,"value":1},
      {"source":2,"target":8,"value":1},
      {"source":3,"target":8,"value":1},
      {"source":2,"target":9,"value":1},
      {"source":3,"target":9,"value":1},
      {"source":4,"target":11,"value":1},
      {"source":5,"target":11,"value":1},
      {"source":9,"target":12,"value":1},
      {"source":10,"target":12,"value":1},
      {"source":11,"target":13,"value":1},
      {"source":12,"target":13,"value":1}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: @StephenThomas data added to the post

Comment: What happens if you replace the troublesome statement with `var c = {"source": 0, "target": 1}`? I'm not sure if D3 can handle an initial links array that mixes indices with object references.

Comment: It should be able to work with references as per the docs. The indices are simply there to make it easy to load JSON data. Once the simulation starts, d3 replaces those indices with references to the objects they represent. I also know it should work because my code is based on this block: http://bl.ocks.org/ericcoopey/6c602d7cb14b25c179a4

Comment: You need to run `force.start()` after adding the link. Any time you change the structure of nodes or links, you have to re-start the layout.  This will initialise a few arrays based on the new data. If you don't do that, the `force.tick()` method will encounter some undefined values in it's calculations and that is where the NaN`s are coming from.

Comment: @CoolBlue yes I get that from the docs but that is what update does, also same things happens even if I put force.start() at start of update function. Also this structure can be seen working in the link to the block two comments up that I gave. I feel this is one of those staring you in the face errors. Explicit d3 error seen is  

if (x == null) this.removeAttribute(name); else this.setAttribute(name, x);

Comment: But you are adding the link _after_ you run `update`. You need to re-start _after_ adding the link. Otherwise it will break on the first tick.

Comment: @CoolBlue yes I have modified my code to do that and still seeing the issue. it was my intention as per the block code to run update after every addition to either force.nodes or force.links

Comment: Ok, you should probably update your post to show that. What about the semicolon you are using in your node id? Maybe that breaks querySelector...

Comment: Also make sure that the `force.start()` happens _before_ the first `force.tick()` after you push the link. Put a console.log inside d3 in `force.tick()` to check. If the tick comes too soon, you should stop the layout before making the change. If you put `links.push(c); force.start()` instead of `links.push(c); update()`, does it still break for example?

Comment: @CoolBlue changed code to: force.stop(); links.push(c);              force.start(); but still no change

Comment: OK, I had a chance to have a closer look... there are basic problems with how you are loading the data into the force...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some basic problems with your code, see [corrected concept](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/8d0943d6e4ecd9916eee/fd1f95430f9ac2cd4b7b6db5cedd86861a2cfba6) below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .link {
      stroke: #2E2E2E;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .node {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .textClass {
      stroke: #323232;
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Droid Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: normal;
      stroke-width: .5;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<!--<script src="d3 CB.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  d3.json("data.json", function (error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    function chart(elementName) {

      // look for the node in the d3 layout
      var findNode = function (name) {
        for (var i in nodes) {
          if (nodes[i]["name"] === name) return nodes[i];
        }
      };

      var width = 960, // default width
        height = 450, // default height
        color = d3.scale.category10(),
        nodes = graph.nodes,
        links = graph.links,
        force = d3.layout.force()
          .nodes(nodes)
          .links([]),
        vis,
        runOnceFlag = true;

      vis = d3.select(elementName)
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("id", "svg")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("perserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
        .append('svg:g');

      var update = function () {
        var link = vis.selectAll("line")
          .data(force.links(), function (d) {
            return d.source + "-" + d.target;
          });

        link.enter().insert("line", "g")
          .attr("id", function (d) {
            return d.source + "-" + d.target;
          })
          .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {
            return d.value / 10;
          })
          .attr("class", "link")
          .style("stroke", "red")
          .transition().duration(5000).style("stroke", "black");
        link.append("title")
          .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;
          });
        link.exit().remove();

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function (d) {
            return d.name;
          });

        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .call(force.drag);

        nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
          .attr("r", 12)
          .attr("id", function (d) {
            return "Node;" + d.name;
          })
          .attr("class", "nodeStrokeClass")
          .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.group);
          });

        nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
          .attr("class", "textClass")
          .attr("x", 14)
          .attr("y", ".31em")
          .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
          });

        node.exit().remove();

        force.on("tick", function () {

          link.attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
          })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
              return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
              return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
              return d.target.y;
            });

          node.attr("transform", function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });

        });

        // Restart the force layout.
        force
          .charge(-120)
          .linkDistance(function (d) {
            return d.value * 100
          })
          .size([width, height])
          .start();
      };

      update();
      var c = {"source": findNode('a'), "target": findNode('b'), value: 1}
      // the line below causes the error
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        force.links().push(c);
        update()
      },2000)
    };
    //
    chart('body');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did a line by line compare of your code against mine, apart from the issue concerning the ordering the the DOM, the error was being caused by the missing 'value' attribute of the link. Thanks

Comment: The level of and the somewhat arbitrary abstraction of d3 can make for interesting mental processes. Sorry about the wild goose chase about `force.start()`; I've seen that symptom so many times and it's always been the same problem. Yes, I think the missing member in your link was the problem. I also think my use of `selection.insert` is (dare I say it?) a little more elegant than the original approach. :p

Comment: Yes totally agree, your use of insert() is quite cool, high five to you :) I will keep you updated of my side project once its complete if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I would be interested for sure.

Comment: here is the side project code. It's 90% complete. It is a re-usable chart with an MVC layout https://github.com/TimeBandit/graphSub